# Create tasks in microsoft outlook using .NET

Tags: .net, outlook

How can i send task /appointments to Microsoft outllook using dot net ? I searched in net and found that we can do this with Microsoft Outlook 10.0/11.0 Object Library

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/sridhar_msd/TaskInOutLook07022007023227AM/TaskInOutLook.aspx
   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sendtaskspgmticly.aspx

Now my question is do i need an microsoft outlook instance running in my server ?  Do i need anything in my client other than a browser ?

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757): Current licensing guidelines prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office.

So you not only need to have it on server, you need to make sure your clients have Office too.
And whose tasks/calender you plan to post to? There isn't a user profile in service.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with Exchange, look up Exchange web services (EWS). It's quite powerful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx